# Dimensión del terminal de Linux

Tags: c

Como se puede determinar el número de líneas que hay en el terminal de Linux ( que está abierto en el momento) ?
Y a este valor asignarle una variable ?de modo que pueda utilizarlo en una función . Gracias.